# XML XSLT Wrap elements to parent element

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XML

```
<GOOITEGDS>
<PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
<PreDocRefAR26>3672</PreDocRefAR26>
<PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
</GOOITEGDS>
```

and I'd like with XSLT to have the following result wrapping the specific elements

```
<GOOITEGDS>
<PREADMREFAR2
<PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
<PreDocRefAR26>3672</PreDocRefAR26>
<PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
</PREADMREFAR2
</GOOITEGDS>
```

Thanks a lot,
Nikos

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when answered. Please post a new question with your radically changed requirements. Make sure to explain the logic required for the transformation. An example is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="GOOITEGDS">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:element name="PREADMREFAR2">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ahhh sorry I wasn't specific enough. I edited my question. I have multiple elements above and below the ones I want to wrap. I populated the XML with some of the elements. Thank you~!

Comment: Good luck with the new question.